# Small Help on stack based operation!

Tags: assembly, stack

Stack Instructions:

```
PUSH A
PUSH B
SUB
POP X
```

**Is** X = A-B 
**or**
X = B-A?

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Depends on the definition of `SUB` ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, `SUB` could be defined either way (as @delnan says).

In practice, most stack-based languages or instruction sets will follow the conventions of [Reverse Polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation): `5 2 -` would be `3`, and can be thought of in terms of stack operations as `push 5; push 2; subtract`.  So, in your example, `X = A-B` would be the more typical expected result.

(A real example: [`isub`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Instructions2.doc6.html#isub) in the JVM.)

Answer (score 0):

So, if I have to demonstrate `A*(B-C)/D-E` with stack operation, I am doing this right:

```
PUSH A
PUSH B
PUSH C
SUB
MUL
PUSH D
DIV
PUSH E
SUB
```

Then, the top of stack would have what `A*(B-C)/D-E` evaluates to. Actually this needs to be done with zero-address format register and i believe using stack this way is how it is done.

Thank you very much for the help.

Highly appreciated.